# AdobeMediaEncoderのAPI

Tags: adobe-brackets

AdobeMediaEncoderのAPIが存在して、8080のポートが開放されていると聞いたのですが
送るパラメータがわからず、うまくレスポンスが取得できません。

具体的な例を教えて下さい

Comment: そもそも質問の元となった記事かもしれないし、有効な情報でもなさそうですが、こんなのがあります。[Adobe Media Encoder CC2014 SDK / API / WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43322235/9014308), [sp00x/node-adobe-media-encoder-webservice](https://github.com/sp00x/node-adobe-media-encoder-webservice)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます
接続することはできましたがJobStatusがNot Foundとなってしまい情報を取得することができません。

<payload version="1.0">
<ServerStatus>Online</ServerStatus>
<JobStatus>Not Found</JobStatus>
<JobId />
<JobProgress />
<Details />
<CompletedJobs />
 </payload>

Comment: 記事とGitHubは古いから今は変わっているのかも。Adobeの資料やサポートに聞いてみては？ [Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/jp/products/media-encoder.html), [Adobe Media Encoder ラーニングとサポート](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/support/media-encoder.html), [AME Web Service Setup](https://community.adobe.com/t5/media-encoder/ame-web-service-setup/td-p/10219360), [コミュニティフォーラム](https://community.adobe.com/t5/media-encoder/bd-p/media-encoder)